# Strange UICollectionView error with high CPU usage in iOS 9

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios9, uicollectionviewlayout

In iOS 8 all went well, but with iOS 9 I get this error message: `the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values`

I have `collectionView`s embedded into `tableView` cells. Any idea?

I tried `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`, but it does not work. `DenseMapBase` method is get called repeatedly.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` is most likely unrelated to this as it affects only the first UIScrollView (or it's descendant like `UITableView`) in your view hierarchy. The "automatical scroll view inset adjustment" means that if you have an `UINavigationBar` in the view, the top content inset of the scroll view is set to the height of the `UINavigationBar` so that the bar doesn't overlap the scroll content when `contentOffset` is zero (scrolled to top), but the content can be scrolled under the bar and if the bar is not fully opaque you can see the content through (e.g. like in Safari).

Please check the **cell sizes returned by the delegate** of the `UICollectionView`. That error is printed when the delegate returns a **cell size that doesn't fit into the `UICollectionView` while respecting content and section insets.** Your collection view's scroll direction is probably horizontal?

If so then the delegate method probably returns too big height value for the cell. Here's an example:

- UICollectionView has dimensions 100pt x 100pt
- Top and bottom content insets are 5pt
- Top and bottom section insets are 0pt (for simplicity)

The maximum height of the cell in this case would be 100pt - 2 * 5pt = 90pt

Comment: right, for collectionView `Min Spacing` `For Lines` were set to 10, I set to 0 in Interface Builder and warning from terminal disappeared, but app still crashes

Comment: @János hmm, the wrong cell sizes shouldn't be able to crash the app, I think the crash is related to something else. Can you post a stacktrace or is it the one in the original question?

Comment: @János hmm, the stack trace didn't help much. Did you already manage to fix this? Looking at the resource usage graphs, it seems like there is an eternal loop somewhere allocating more and more memory until the app crashes. Did you check that you don't accidentally call i.e. `reloadData` from delegate methods which could cause this?